# Writeline not writing certain tabs to output file

Tags: c#, string-formatting, delimiter

I am trying to write a tab delimited text file with data similar to what is below:

```
ColHead1 ColHead2 ... Colhead10

Row1Dat1 Row1Dat2 ... Row1Dat10

Row2Dat1 Row2Dat2 ... Row2Dat10
```

however, when debugging my code, I notice that there a few tabs that don't appear. Here is the code I am currently trying:

```
string columnHeaders = string.Format("ColHead1\tColHead2\tColHead3\tColHead4\tColHead5\tColHead6\tColHead7\tColHead8\tColHead9\tColHead10");
fileW.WriteLine(columnHeaders);
string row1 = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10);
fileW.WriteLine(row1);
string row2 = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}", val11, val12, val13, val14, val15, val16, val17, val18, val19, val20);
fileW.WriteLine(row2);
```

Specifically, when I look at the value in row1 or row2, it is formatted as below (on either row):

```
dat1    dat2(noTabHere)dat3    dat4    dat5    dat6    dat7    dat8    dat9(noTabHere)dat10
```

Why aren't those two tabs being inserted and what can I do to ensure they're inserted properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe those tabs became too small because the preceding value is too wide?

```
0   1   2   15  162 102819201924
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Comment: This was the reason, so I'll use string.Format("{0,length}\t") instead